# ¿Obtener posición de listview desde clase cursor Adapter?

Tags: android, android-studio

como logro obtener el id posicion de listview desde cursor adapter. 
Esta es mi clase

```
    public class ClientesCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    String idC;
    int int_id;
    public ClientesCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c, 0);
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cliente, viewGroup, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView nombrecliente = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_cliente_nombre);
        TextView nombrelocal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_nombre_negocio);
        ImageView btn_next= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_next_cliente);
        View mView =(View) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator_status);
        String nombre = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Cnombre));
        String negocio = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Ccodigo));
        idC = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Cid));
        long idlng=cursor.getLong(0);
        int_id=Integer.parseInt(idC);
        int_id=int_id-6;
        idC=""+idlng;
        nombrecliente.setText(nombre + "id:  "+idC);
        nombrelocal.setText(negocio);
        mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("in view", "onClick id :"+idC);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ClienteDetalleActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("clienteid", idC);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Y cuando hago click en el listener me sale esto en el logcat

```
05-08 10:02:47.280 20327-20327/com.***.***.csp***m I/in view: onClick id :6
```

05-08 10:03:16.756 20327-20327/com.***.***.**I/in view: onClick id :6

Siempre me devuelve la posicion en más 6

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del método `bindView()` puedes obtener la posición del mismo cursor mediante `getPosition()`:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {

  int posicion = cursor.getPosition();
  ...
  ...

}
```

---

> [**Cursor, método getPosition()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) :  Devuelve la posición actual del cursor en el
>   conjunto de filas.

Comment: Acabo de intentar de esa manera   int idlng=cursor.getPosition();, pero en las primeras cinco filas me devuelve 0 (onClick id :0), luego de esas me devuelve con dos posiciones mas, es decir si presiono en la posicion 6 me envia 8, pero al momento de colocarle junto al nombre(nombrecliente.setText(nombre + "id:  "+idC);) para ver su poscion si me envian la correcta.

Comment: el llamado del listener es independiente de la obtención de la posición por esta razón se muestra correctamente al mostrarlo en la vista. Si deseas mostrar una posición al realizar click te recomiendo por ejemplo agregar la posición como tag de la vista, mediante view.setTag(posicion)  y al dar click obtenerla mediante view.getTag();

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una interfaz para el `onClickListener`

```
public interface onClickListener(){
  void onClickItem(int position);
}
```

Desde la actividad que declares el adaptador tendrás que hacer que esta implemente la interfaz

```
public class myActivity extends AppCompactActivity implements onClickListener {
 ...

 @Override
 public void onClickItem(int position){

 }
}
```

Y cuando declares el adaptador mandar el contexto para que reciba el evento

`MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this);`

```
public void MyAdapter extends BasicAdapter(){

 private final onClickListener;

 public void MyAdapter(OnclickListener onclickListener){
  this.onClickListener = onclickListener;
 }

}
```

Y cuando declares el evento de click en la vista

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClickListener.onItemClick(position);
            }
        });
```

Con esto recibirás la posición en tu actividad, pero puedes implementar la interfaz donde necesites que te llegue.